# Microsoft Speech Plataform em Português

Tags: c#

Caros, tenho uma aplicação usando reconhecimento de fala que funciona muito bem em Inglês (en-US), no entanto quando tentei usar para português (pt-BR) os resultados são péssimos, parece até que está tentando reconhecer outra língua! Estou fazendo algo de errado?

Qual é o certo a se usar, Speech SDK 5.1 ou Speech Platform 11.0?

Tenho instalado:

Microsoft Speech Platform x64 v11.0

Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1

Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1 Language Pack

Microsoft Server Speech Recognition Language - TELE (pt-BR)

Microsoft Server Speech Recognition Language - TELE (en-US)

E algumas outros idiomas também.

Aqui está meu código:

```
public static string ProcessAudio(Stream input, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            _recon = "";

            CultureInfo cInfo = new CultureInfo(language);
            SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(cInfo);
            sre.SetInputToWaveStream(input);

            Choices options = new Choices();
            options.Add(new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" });


            options.Add(new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q",
                                       "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" });


            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(new GrammarBuilder(options, 5, 50));
            gb.Culture = cInfo;

            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
            sre.LoadGrammar(g);

            sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
            sre.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechHypothesized);

            sre.Recognize();

            sre.Dispose();

            return _recon;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        _recon += e.Result.Text;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
    }

    static void sre_SpeechHypothesized(object sender, SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Result.Text} conf: {e.Result.Confidence}");
    }
```

Comment: Como é que o usuário interage? O que você pretende reconhecer? Simplesmente soletrar letras e números?

Comment: Perdão pela demora, eu recebo um arquivo de áudio com as letras e números para interpretação. Não há interação direta com o usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instale primeiro o Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime (Version 11) respectivo a sua plataforma. [Aqui tem o 32 e o 64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225)
2. Instale o pacote de voz Heloisa versão 11 (Esse instalador não tem muita elegancia, logo se fecha e ta pronto, mas é isso mesmo) [Aqui tem download de várias opções](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224). Teste com a Heloisa primeiro, pois o tutorial é feito pra ela.
3. Execute o script **TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0.reg** respectivo a sua plataforma (32 ou 64)
4. Pronto, agora deve funcionar sem problemas.

Testedo no Windows 7 64 ok

Testado no Windows 8 64 ok

Arquivos:

**TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0 x64.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0]
@="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (pt-BR, Heloisa)"
"416"="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (pt-BR, Heloisa)"
"CLSID"="{a12bdfa1-c3a1-48ea-8e3f-27945e16cf7e}"
"LangDataPath"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Speech\\Tokens\\TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0\\MSTTSLocptBR.dat"
"VoicePath"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Speech\\Tokens\\TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0\\HeloisaT"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0\Attributes]
@=""
"Age"="Adult"
"Gender"="Female"
"Language"="416"
"Name"="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (pt-BR, Heloisa)"
"Vendor"="Microsoft"
"Version"="11.0"
```

**TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0. x86.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0]
@="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (pt-BR, Heloisa)"
"416"="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (pt-BR, Heloisa)"
"CLSID"="{a12bdfa1-c3a1-48ea-8e3f-27945e16cf7e}"
"LangDataPath"="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Speech\\Tokens\\TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0\\MSTTSLocptBR.dat"
"VoicePath"="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Speech\\Tokens\\TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0\\HeloisaT"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_pt-BR_Heloisa_11.0\Attributes]
@=""
"Age"="Adult"
"Gender"="Female"
"Language"="416"
"Name"="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (pt-BR, Heloisa)"
"Vendor"="Microsoft"
"Version"="11.0"
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não estou mais trabalhando neste projeto, não consigo testar a solução.